# Powershell Continue where I left off in a loop

Tags: powershell, loops, variables

Hi I have a script that gets all Users from a set of Office Location. I then run a script to get all servers where the user is logging on, and get the windows-event to check if the user has logged on to the computer or not. This is working fine, The script takes a long time sometimes its over 800 users to check on 100+ servers. So the script will stop. I need a way to restart the script, but not start all over from the top of my $USERS variable.. I export the values of users logged inn into a csv file. I import this file and read the last entry user. I then want the script to continue from that user entry index .

So I would like to have a way to check user then set the index to start from lets say user number 3 then prosses the rest 4 - end.

```
$lastuser = (import-csv -path "Path to csv file").UserName[-1]
Ray
Tod
Burt # Lets say the script terminates here, I want it to continue from here and then procsess the rest
Ali
Mohamed
Annie.....
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way. Either gather the list of users and process them or start a job `Start-Job` doing your action and continue with the loop.

Comment: You have an array and can use SKIP(integer) to ignore the items already processed.  So normally you would set the skip to zero to do entire list.  When you resume you can set the skip value to a larger number

Comment: Can you share the code you're currently using. As mentioned above, there might be a better way to implement this.

Comment: Why does it stop?  You can try workflows.

Comment: Thank you for all answers :) and AS mentiond in the comments, Yes I tried with start-job witch works better. js2010 well as I ran it in an active RDP session the session got disconnected .. and when I came back the Powershell script did not continue and no CPU load.. ??? And the server reboots at knight so that happened :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following to get index of the last user:

```
$users = @("Ray","Tod","Burt","Ali")
$lastUser = "Burt"
$userList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$userList.AddRange([string[]]$users)
$userList
$index = $userList.IndexOf($lastUser)
$index
```

Comment: Thank you @jdwen I will try this out. I tried another variant to my script where I exclude building up my $USERS array excluding the once already processed. Witch works :) But Hey New-Object ?? Is NEW-Experience for me :) Thank you for all answers :)

Comment: It is c# code.  Need a list instead of an array for the IndexOf() method to work

Comment: You don't need a list: `[array]` supports `.IndexOf()` too (via the `IList` interface, which PowerShell automatically surfaces): Try `@("Ray","Tod","Burt","Ali").IndexOf('Burt')`. The caveat in both cases is that the lookup is case-_sensitive_, whereas PowerShell is generally case-_insensitive_.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside questions raised in the comments as to whether there are ways to ensure uninterrupted runs to begin with:

If you can rely on the value of `$USERS` not to have changed between runs, and  assuming that the users are always processed *sequentially*, you don't need to perform any lookups at all:

The *count* of the rows in your CSV file is then the *index* into your `$USERS` variable at which you have to resume processing:

```
# Get all not-yet-processed elements from the $Users array.
$Users[(Import-Csv "Path to csv file").Count..$Users.Count-1]
```